# how to implement internalization in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to implement internalization in angular particularly for currency symbol. I want to load the currency based on the localization.

I've some thing like below In the login page.

```
English-UK  English-US
```

When user clicks i'm localizing language and storing language info to use the localization for other pages.  I also want to load correct currency symbol when user goes to other page.

for example.

if user choosen English-US - in home page    12 | currency -> should display  $12 ( us dollar)

if user choosen English-UK - in home page    12 | currency -> should display  £12  ( uk pound )

Comment: According to the angular documentation, in angular 1.2.2 and probably even before that internationalization has been supported. See this page for more information: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: I know internalization is supported in angular. How would u implement them for more thang one language in the application?